# Serialisation differences between putting an object in Session and other serialisation types

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-state

**Background**

We have reports that are quite large that are saved by users. The state these reports are in are saved into the session (`HttpSessionState`).

Obviously this is bad practice and needs to be removed. Really not sure why it was written like this in the first place.

**The issue**

There's a manager in the code that handles saving these reports, which is essentially the following code:

```
    public T GetObject<T>(string reportGuid)
    {
        try
        {
            return (T)context.Session[reportGuid];
        }
        catch
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }

    public void SetObject(string reportGuid, dynamic value)
    {
        this.context.Session.Add(reportGuid, value);
    }
```

Simple enough. This, on the whole works but makes sessions absolutely huge (we've seen them over 1MB). Our sessions are stored in SQLServer mode so at some point (I'm assuming) the session is serialised and stored in the `ASPStateTempSessions` table.

We tried to replace this with various serialisers such Microsoft's own XML Serialiser, JSON.Net's JsonSerialiser, and a Binary formatter. All of these were written to a file and then retrieved.

However this then broke as one particular field which was usually populated with a string for some reason was now missing.

The weird thing is I have no idea when this field is being set.

```
public string XsltString
{
    get { return this.xsltString; }
    set { this.xsltString = value; }
}
```

This is the field in question. I've put a breakpoint on the set and it never gets called with the original code.

In the old method, this is what happens:

1. Report manager calls the `SetObject` method the ID and the Report (`value`). At this point `XsltString` is not set and is null.
2. Some work is done on the report and then `GetObject` is called to populate it with the new information before being set again. When `GetObject` is called and the object is retrieved from the Session, `XsltString` now has a value set. When using a method writing to disk it is not set

So I suppose I've got two questions.

1. How does Session actually serialise / deserialise objects? I assume it was binary but I get different results writing to disk than it does with writing to Session.
2. How is `XsltString` getting set? The set method is never called, and when the object goes into session it isn't populated. I've put breakpoints on the Get and Set for this and nothing is there. I've also checked the code and nowhere else is accessing it except through this class.

Comment: When reading binary, no constructors are called, no getters/setters, the object is build in memory completely. So I guess this is what happens. Maybe there are different kind serializations going on depending on the scenaria...just guessing

Comment: I thought this, which is why I put the break point on the setter but that never gets called even after coming back out of session.

Comment: If you read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479041.aspx#aspnetsessionstate_topic5 it says that a binary serializer is used (or a special serializer basically for value types)

Comment: `BinaryFormatter ` was the formatter we were using when we first replaced the Session storage so it must be elsewhere.

Comment: I'm still confused what your actual problem is. You say you are not using the session anymore and you are serializing to disk and now `XsltString` is not populated anymore, correct?

Comment: Essentially, yes. In the old method using Session, it went in `null` and came out populated with a string. When we replaced the get and set it went in null and came out null. We're a bit bemused as to how this is happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91836/discussion-between-derape-and-daniel-edwards).